# Talmud Yerushalmi Editions

Tags: jewish-books

Which edition of the Talmud Yerushalmi would you recommend? I am looking for a hard copy, all Hebrew/Aramaic edition with clear print, helpful commentary, and a high level of accuracy.

Comment: english translation?

Comment: If you're looking for an English translation, Artscroll literally just released their Schottenstein edition of the whole Yerushalmi!

Comment: If you are into serious learning, the Artscroll Hebrew Yerushalmi is truly exceptional. I have seen very advanced talmidei chachamim use it for its notes and commentary. Its "Vilna" pages are taken from Oz vehadar. The Hebrew version will be complete in about a year but many masechtot are already available. I finished learning Shviit and Moed Katan with it, am in the middle of Challah and wonder how people learned before artscroll....

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for a hard copy edition in Hebrew, I would highly recommend the ArtScroll edition:

[ArtScroll Talmud Yerushalmi Hebrew](https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/HYT.html)

[image]

Since it's ArtScroll, I am sure the commentaries given in the edition are helpful :) (my honest opinion). It is great for learning.

Comment: I should have mentioned two more specifications. I am looking for a hard copy edition without English translation.

Comment: I edited the post to make sure it fits with your specifications.

Comment: When they say "Hebrew" do they mean it's a translation into Hebrew? Or that the text is in the original Aramaic and they're calling it Hebrew?

Comment: I'm confused how you don't know. Have you not used this work? On what basis are you recommending it?

Comment: It seems the Aramaic words are translated into Hebrew. - "Every word of the text appears, vowelized, and with Aramaic words translated"

Comment: sample page images available here https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/artscroll-schottenstein-edition-talmud-yerushalmi---mesechta-eruvin-volume-2-HYER2.html

Comment: @joshk similar to their English work, the Hebrew translates all Aramaic into Hebrew on one side of the page. Unlike the Bavli, they provide variant readings as there is a lot more confusion in Yerushalmi as to the correct reading/understanding of the text in Yerushalmi

Answer (score 0):

The Oz Vahadar Edition is excellent.  It even includes Rav Chaim Kanievsky's notes on the daf.

https://oz-vehadar.net/product/%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%96-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8/

Comment: Do you know if the compact version's print is easy to read?

Comment: Their compact everything else I've ever seen is easy to read. I wouldn't worry.